# How can I access the objects in model layer into view layer

Tags: object, view, model, storage, oracle-adf

Is there any way I can access the objects in AM implementation layer in my backing bean in view layer in ADF?

Something like where I can set the variable in ADF AM impl and get it in my backing/managed bean of view layer.

Example: I can set my object in AM impl using `this.getDBTransaction().getSession().getUserData().put("myobject",new Object());`

I need to access this in my managed bean.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an AM method for whatever you want to do and then expose it in AM client interface. This will make method available in AM data control and from there it could added in your page bindings.